# External Variable on ERC-721

Tags: solidity, contract-development, nft, erc-721, contract-debugging

I'm fairly new to smart contracts and I'd like to know how I can pass an external variable to my `ERC-721` contract. For example, I'd like the following function to return an external variable:

```
function _baseURI() override internal view virtual returns (string memory) {
    return my_variable_here;
}
```

I'm compiling the contract at [remix.ethereum.org](https://remix.ethereum.org/) and I'd like to type the variable on the left side, like this:

[image]

The image above is just an example because the real variable I want to pass is an IPFS url, which I don't want to hard-code.

---

### Contact

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

import "erc721a/contracts/ERC721A.sol";

contract test123 is ERC721A {
    constructor() ERC721A("test123", "test123") {}

    function mint(uint256 quantity) external payable {
        // `_mint`'s second argument now takes in a `quantity`, not a `tokenId`.
        _mint(msg.sender, quantity);
    }

    function _baseURI() override internal view virtual returns (string memory) {
        return "ipfs://bafybeigshu4xqcajjkbqw24cea6shz2vh7dibp7yowjmxo4yg32aoma123/";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. You can pass it in the constructor and set it to a state variable:

```js
contract test123 is ERC721A {

    string public baseUri;

    constructor(string memory _baseUri) ERC721A("test123", "test123") {
        baseUri = _baseUri;
    }

    function mint(uint256 quantity) external payable {
        // `_mint`'s second argument now takes in a `quantity`, not a `tokenId`.
        _mint(msg.sender, quantity);
    }

    function _baseURI() override internal view virtual returns (string memory) {
        return baseUri;
    }

}
```

2. You can create a setter method to be able to change it dynamically, that only the owner can call:

```js
import "erc721a/contracts/ERC721A.sol";

contract test123 is ERC721A {

    string public baseUri;
    address public owner;

    constructor() ERC721A("test123", "test123") {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function mint(uint256 quantity) external payable {
        // `_mint`'s second argument now takes in a `quantity`, not a `tokenId`.
        _mint(msg.sender, quantity);
    }

    function _baseURI() override internal view virtual returns (string memory) {
        return baseUri;
    }

    function getBaseURI(string memory _baseUri) external onlyOwner {
        baseUri = _baseUri;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Not owner");
        _;
    }

}
```

3. Or both, setting it in the constructor and also being able to change it dynamically:

```js
contract test123 is ERC721A {

    string public baseUri;
    address public owner;

    constructor(string memory _baseUri) ERC721A("test123", "test123") {
        baseUri = _baseUri;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function mint(uint256 quantity) external payable {
        // `_mint`'s second argument now takes in a `quantity`, not a `tokenId`.
        _mint(msg.sender, quantity);
    }

    function _baseURI() override internal view virtual returns (string memory) {
        return baseUri;
    }

    function getBaseURI(string memory _baseUri) external onlyOwner {
        baseUri = _baseUri;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Not owner");
        _;
    }

}
```

And from the `_baseURI` function you simply return this `baseUri` state variable.

Comment: I'll go with option 2, but I'll keep the other answers for reference. Thank you so much for the help.